# Altera Arria V latest software for OpenCL

Tags: opencl, intel-fpga

I recently bought a new Altera Arria V board [1](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=166&No=893). I am planning to use it to design a certain application using OpenCL.
Unfortunately, I didn't find so far the required software to get it work. I mean by that the Altera RTE for OpenCL and the required driver (aclsoc_drv.ko).

I would be grateful if you could help me how I can find the latest software!

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the manual about how to install and what you need to install which you should be able to find here: [Arria V SoC Development Kit and SoC Embedded Design Suite](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=166&No=893&PartNo=3)

OpenCL runtime environment and SDK you can find here: [Altera SDK for OpenCL](http://dl.altera.com/opencl/)

Also [Altera OpenCL guides](https://www.altera.com/products/design-software/embedded-software-developers/opencl/documentation.html#Guides) will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you first for your answer!. Actually, I've already read these documents. None of them provides a link to where to find the required software. Secondly, for the host machine part (OpenCL), every thing works well since I normally used it with Cyclone V Sockit. However, it seems that Terasics does not provide the board package for this board. The board should contain a description of this architecture that AOC uses to generates the design.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe contact Terasic or check Altera forum.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand to your problem correctly, you are missing the required BSP and the base design to support OpenCL development for your Arria V board.

For this problem, please check with the board vendor (customer support) for the availability of the two items.

To be able to develop under Altera OpenCL framework, you need to load a basic design file on to the flash ROM / configuration device on the board. This is to provide some necessary IP support for the basic PCIe and memory access. It is usually provided with the BSP from the board vendor.

Along with the basic design file, drivers should be included as well for your host to recognise the OpenCL device.

Until you sort out the above missing parts, your OpenCL development environment should be up and running. Good luck!